# Limit point of a sequence

Tags: real-analysis

**Question**

Let {$a_k$} be a sequence arising by an arbitrary one-to-one indexing of the elements of the matrix {$n^{1/3} - m^{1/3}$},n,m $\in $N . Show that every real number is a limit point of this sequence

How to prove that in any interval (a,b) there is at least one term of the sequence?

Comment: First step: get good upper and lower bounds on $(m+1)^{1/3}-m^{1/3}$.

Comment: If i suppose a set A={$n \in N : n^{1/3}-n_o^{1/3} \leq a $}, i can prove the desired result . But i am not able to prove why this set will be non-empty and bounded above?

Comment: I don't understand your comment. Can you try to engage with my comment?

Comment: Ok. since {$(m+1)^{1/3}- m^{1/3}$} approaches zero when m tends to infinity ,{$(m+1)^{1/3}- m^{1/3}$}$ \leq $ b-a .

Comment: Right. But how fast does it approach zero? I want good upper and lower bounds. I want functions $f$ and $g$ such that $f(m)\le(m+1)^{1/3}-m^{1/3}\le g(m)$ with $g(m)-f(m)$ as small as you can make it.

Comment: Oh.. I see your point . Let me try. Thanks .

Comment: g(m) =$\frac{ 1}{2 m^{1/2}}$ and f(m)=$\frac{ 1}{2(m+1)^{1/2}}$

Comment: Is this right? What to do now ?

Comment: I'm not sure how you got those – I'm not sure they're correct – but let's assume they are. You can use what you've done to get good bounds on $(m+j)^{1/3}-m^{1/3}$ for $j$ not too large. Then you can work on taking $m$ large enough to get $(m+j)^{1/3}-m^{1/3}$ between any given $a$ and $b$.

Comment: Thanks. ........